# Display PopUp when network connection is down in AngularJS/Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, network-programming

I'd like to prevent users from using an android App (made with AngularJS) as soon as they go offline, and let them use it again when you're online.

For this, I know which JS functions call, using Cordova, [It's pretty clear how to do it, using events](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.network-information).

However, how would you organise your AngularJS code sothat this works with every controllers in my app? I mean, in all pages of the app, if the network goes down, I need to display a big red error popup that say "Hey guy, network is down, this popup is gonna stay here as long as the network stays down".

Should I create a service and call it in every controller of my app? This seems dirty to me to paste the same `callCheckConnection()` function is every controller. Is there a highler level way?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create an external script that check the internet connection .call the  function  from every controller that you want to check internet

Comment: I have many controllers. Do you think there is a trick to avoid calling the script from every controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must register the event in app.js not in controllers. Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
  //Show the popup
}
```